# Core Data in 3 UIViewControllers

Tags: core-data, uiviewcontroller

This sounds like a newbie question, but I have a couple of Applications where I am stuck with the same concept. I have 3 `UIViewController`s:

- The first is the Root Controller which is `UITableView` (in another
  App a Collection View)
- The second is normal `UIViewController` that shows the details of the selected item in the Root Controller
- The third is the Edit Controller where I want to edit the content of this Object, for which I  reuse the Same `AddViewController` where I use to add a new Object.

The savings goes fine with no error, although, when I am returning from the Edit Controller to Detail one , the Detail still shows the Old Data. It doesn't update the data until I return to the root again.

I need to find a way so the data in the Detail view is updated when I hot back from the Edit View. This Problem is troubling in many Application I am working on right now.

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve your goal is the following: within you edit controller you need to say to your detail controller *"Dear detail controller, I've just updated the content, please refresh!"*.

How to do it? Set up a delegate or a notification (In both cases the detail controller will respond or listen for your edit controller) and then execute a new fresh request for the data you are interested in and update the interface.

P.S. I think the detail controller does not update since you have executed the request in its `viewDidLoad`. Am I wrong? If you provide some code we could help you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well,my  Problem reside in the Executing Fresh Request for the Data , how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

well Here is the Code for the didselectrow in the root

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailnewViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailnewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailnewViewController" bundle:nil];
    Card *selectedItem = (Card *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    detailViewController.itcard = selectedItem;
    detailViewController.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;
    detailViewController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    [selectedItem release];


}
```

Here is the Code for the Detailnewviewcontroller & you are right i am Excuting the Request in viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    cardnumberlabel.text=itcard.CardNumber;
    namelabel.text=itcard.Name;
    phonelabel.text=itcard.phonenumber;
    websitelabel.text=itcard.site;
}
```

Thank you for your Reply , i will Try the Delegate for view c

Comment: Solved !The Answer is ViewwillApear , Thanks:)